# How can I print value from embedded document in side an array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Here is the document from which I want to print name value (Despacito) only.

```
{
    "movie" : [
            {
                    "song" : {
                            "name" : "Despacito"
                    }
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `object.movie[0].song.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

movie is an array, so you can access the index by movie[0]. Then song is an object. You can just do

**`result.movie[0].song.name`**

**DEMO**

```js
var result = {
    "movie" : [
            {
                    "song" : {
                            "name" : "Despacito"
                    }
            }
    ]
};

console.log(result.movie[0].song.name);
```